# ckeditor getSelection not working in safari/mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, fckeditor

This is what i have written to get href from link in ckeditor

```
var selection = editor.getSelection();
range = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0],
el = editor.document.createElement('div');
el.append(range.cloneContents());
var selectedHTML = el.getHtml();
```

selectedHTML gives html with anchor tag but safari doesnt give the same

Comment: Read this http://ckeditor.com/comment/135292#comment-135292

Comment: thanks for the link but i think my issue is if i have some anchor tag with href why safari can't get href attribute from it. for eg : <a href="www.google.com" >google</a> in ckedtior on clicking google text i will get href from $(selectedHTML).attr('href') in chrome,ff,ie.